# pausing a video and audio

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a video which is 40 seconds long, I want to make it 55 seconds long, I wanted that the video's first frame along with it's audio freezes (frame freezes) for the first 15 seconds and after the countdown of 15 seconds it starts running so that I can get the video 55 seconds long, is it possible ?
I tried a trick but it didn't work, I will share it with you. I took a screen shot of the first frame of the video, saved it in 1.jpg, then I ran the following command.

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 15 -i 1.jpg  -c:v libx264 -vf 'scale=-2:min(1080\,trunc(ih/2)*2)' -r 30 1.mp4`

Afterwards I tried this video combine with the original video so that this 1.mp4 will run for 15 seconds with the first frame and then after 15 seconds the original video will start running, it works but in the process the seconds/original video louses its sound, the command which I used it following.

`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy out.mp4`

list.txt has the names of the videos.

Can someone help me in achieving this ?

Comment: You might have better luck with an answer at superuser.com. This is a programming and developer site. Hence why you have been voted down.